# No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'setBackgroundImage:forState:'

Tags: ios, uibutton

this error happened in **AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIButton+AFNetworking.m**.and when i go into UIButton.h,find that there no method  `setBackgroundImage` which should be there.

i find that the error happened whenever u use setBackgroundImage. it seems not relevant to the library

`UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width, 0, 10, 10)];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"something.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

this is the code here!
anyone can help me?thanks

Comment: You need to describe question more and clearly  so we can understand .

Comment: sorry for that. I try to edit it again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method with signature *

> setBackgroundImage:forState:'

*
Use
- (void)setBackgroundImageForState:(UIControlState)state
                           withURL:(NSURL *)url;
or 
- (void)setBackgroundImageForState:(UIControlState)state
                           withURL:(NSURL *)url
                  placeholderImage:(nullable UIImage *)placeholderImage;

Comment: I did import it.and i find that the error happened whenever u use setBackgroundImage. it seems not relevant to the library.

Comment: there is a setBackgroudImage:forState method for UIButton here![link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton)